# Dataset for German domain names (.de)

Tags: data-request, internet, germany

I'm looking for a new DNS domain in Germany (`.de`) for a new service.

It would be very helpful to search `.de` domains using wildcards (regular expressions), e.g.

```
mysuperservice[0-9]+.de
mysuper-[a-z]+-[0-9]+.de
```

Since I did not find such a public service, I am looking for a open data dataset with `.de` domain names.

I'm only looking for domain names, not for contacts or other information about domains.

Ideally the dataset should be up to date (not too old...).

I found this [question on Stack Overflow](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1951/dataset-of-domain-names), but it is rather old and is covering all [top-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain), not just a single domain.

Comment: The DNS census in the answer you link will have a separate file/folder for .de domains, so I think that’s a valid answer here (albeit an older resource)

Comment: @philshem but this data is from 2013 - 6 years old. Useless for domain name searches in 2019.

Comment: Have you looked at commoncrawl.org ?

Comment: @BarryCarter yes, but I have to build my own list there. I cannot find  any downloads provided.

Comment: You can download the list of pages at https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/cc-index/collections/index.html and should be able to extract the domain names. I thought they had a direct link to domain names only, but maybe not. The last time I did this, I found 2,604,685 domain names ending in .de (but this includes subdomains like abc.xyz.de) -- I'm not sure if what you've found so far is better.

Comment: check out the new answer here: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/17724/1511

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is all I need (thanks to @philshem):

https://github.com/tb0hdan/domains

This repo containes crawled domain names, top level domains as well as subdomains.

It's a good start for my searching purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be very far from Open Data. But why?

Found some ideas on how to generate/get such a list [here](https://www.seohelfer.de/domains/eine-liste-mit-de-domains-erstellen-38.html) anyway:

- generate domain permutations and test all of them
- download links from wikipedia and extract domain names
- Alexa rank provide a domain list of top domains
- buy it from [Domaindatenbank](https://www.datenshop.de/produkt/de-domaindatenbank) for 350 EUR
- buy it from [Sellfy](https://sellfy.com/p/RhJw/) for 19 EUR

And all of these lists do only contain the domain name, no contact details, company data or the like - just what I need.